# Whatsapp Api sent message not received

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapi

I am using mgp25/Chat-API to send and receive messages, before it was working fine but now for some days.

The onGetMessage never gets called nor does the receiver get a blue tick.

Here is my code :

```
$username = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
$password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=";
$w = new WhatsProt($username, "TestinGWhatsApp", false, false);
$events = new MyEvents($w);
$events->setEventsToListenFor($events->activeEvents);
$w->connect();
$w->loginWithPassword($password);
$w->sendPing();
$w->pollMessage();
$w->getMessages();
$w->disconnect();
```

Any help here??

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: No errors but the onGetMessage is not triggering